# jquery other links is active when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i want to when scrolling it makes an active link one only active link and the others remove active ,the navbar is fixed, when it is active the link add class and the class name is active and when one link is clicked the other links should be unactive (remove class active) but it dosn't work , when i scroll down all the links are active please help

my active class css

```
    .block{
    height: 1200px;
}

.block:first-of-type{
    margin-top: 1200px;
}

.navbar{
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.active{
    color: #000000 !important;
}
```

my navbar and body

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#services">services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#action">action</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#method">method</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
              <li ><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li ><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul>
    <li class="block" class="block" id="services">services</li>
      <li class="block" class="block" id="action">action</li>
      <li class="block" class="block" id="method">method</li>
  </ul>
```

my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Add active class on navbar link and remove from siblings
"use strict";

$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.block').each(function(){
        
        if($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top){
            // console.log($(this).attr('id'));

            var blockId = $(this).attr('id');
            $('a.nav-link[href^="#' +blockId+'"]').addClass('active');
            $('.nav-link').removeClass('active');
        }
        
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You are immediately removing the `active` class from all links after you set the currently active one. You need to remove the `active` class from all the other links *first*, then apply the new one.

Swap the order of these lines:

```js
$('a.nav-link[href^="#' +blockId+'"]').addClass('active');
$('.navbar a').removeClass('active');
```

Becomes:

```js
$('.navbar a').removeClass('active');
$('a.nav-link[href^="#' +blockId+'"]').addClass('active');
```

The editor here struggled with your layout, so here's a codepen showing the above: https://codepen.io/29b6/pen/ZErMGpJ?editors=1111

This works fine, but bear in mind that listening to `scroll` events is quite an inefficient solution, especially as you're just looping over a bunch of DOM elements each time. You might want to read up about the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for a more passive approach.

Comment: it worked but why it should be addClass first then removeClass what is the difference?

Comment: Think about it: you're adding the class to one specific link then removing it from all of them immediately after. *All of them* - including the one you just added it to.